# PHP open SSH session

Tags: php, ssh

I am actually creating script which makes centralized ssh hosts. It means that all hostnames and addresses are stored in database in specific groups so everyone in team can have the same and fresh, updated machines. Everything were fine untill i try to shell_exec()...script prompt password but after typing its stuck.

I do not want to execute remote command via ssh, just open ssh session for user. Users have to execute script from Linux shell by typing "php script.php"

Thanks

There is my simple script:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo "##############################\n";
echo "##        SSH SCRIPT        ##\n";
echo "##############################\n";
$result = getGroups(); 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['group_id'].") ".$row['name']."\n";
    }
echo "Select:";
} else {
    echo "No groups";
}


$groupID=trim(fgets(STDIN));    

$result = getHosts($groupID);   
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['host_id'].") ".$row['hostname']."\n";
    }
echo "Select:";
} else {
    echo "0";
}

$hostID=trim(fgets(STDIN));    
$result = getAddress($hostID);      
ssh($result);    

#### Functions ####
function getAddress($hostID) {
    require("db.php");
    $sql = "SELECT address FROM hosts WHERE host_id=".$hostID."";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        return $row['address'];      
    }
}

function getHosts($groupID) {
    require("db.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE group_id=".$groupID."";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    return $result;
}

function getGroups() {
    require("db.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM groups";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    return $result;
}

function ssh($ip) {
    shell_exec('ssh root@'.$ip.'');
}

?>
```

Comment: Other suggestion: turn this into a web application that either dynamically creates a script or calls a SSH URL handler.

Comment: It can't be created as web application :(